# force explanation for dropping flag request

Tags: feature-request, flags, answer-quality

Hello,

IMO it would be a great idea to force the person who drops a flag (mentioning shortcomings in the original post) to reason. In particular, I doubt that an answer like the first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447936/using-php-cakephp-for-a-payment-gateway/5450464) matches quality standards on SO, as it is no real answer.

Kind regards, Benjamin.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Did somebody flag your answer?

Comment: Pekka, no. If A flags B's post with a flag F and moderator M does not see a reason to consider F and dismisses it, then M should be forced to explain why he dismissed F to A.

Comment: It's confusing because your links (in this and the duplicate) aren't to the question, or the flagged answer, but to your (competing) answer. I think the edit by Adam is a better way to deal with the answer.

Comment: to be fair - I only just discovered that myself - there *was* a somewhat offensive line in the answer @benjamin is talking about, enough to warrant an offensive flag IMO. [Revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5447955/revisions)

Comment: Kate Gregory, a simple c&p error, sorry. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moderators handle hundreds of flags daily.  It's not reasonable to ask them to justify their decision each time.

When you disagree with a moderator's decision, post here and request the community justify the moderator, if you feel you need justification.

In this particular case, I disagree with the moderator for the reason of "be nice".

Even though the person who answered said, "nothing personal" the implied insult was quite clear.

Comment: Adam Davis, I mean the first answer in regard to the time posted (the shorter in terms of written text). The discussion as you suggested can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84923/questioning-a-moderators-decision-on-a-rejected-flag

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer to address the particular post, and I've edited the post to remove the insult.  The post itself isn't wrong, but it is offensive.

Comment: As it looks like the other moderators do not like your idea of another opened discussion, this has to remain the main QA-thread. Sorry that I have to remove the green check in this case. Yours

Comment: Adam Davis, thank you very much for closing the "feedback-loop". Unfortunately my flag weight should be 120 by now (as I was right) but is still reduced to 100.

Comment: @Benjamin I don't think you should worry too much about your flag weight. Keep flagging the things you think require attention, dispute the odd case, and spend time helping others.  The moderators are elected volunteers who have varying opinions and limited time.  Just like down votes on good answers, you'll have to let some things roll off your back.

Comment: Thank you very much again Adam Davis.